# While use @pytest.mark.parametrize and Selenium I got "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute_script'"

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I use Selenium + Python and I need a parametrized test for testing images but got an error:
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute_script'`
This is my code:

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

**tests.py**

```
# get list of images
def get_images_list(driver):
    images_list = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('img')")
    return images_list

# test every image
@pytest.mark.parametrize("image", get_images_list(driver))
def test_images(driver, image):
    driver.get('https://openweathermap.org/')
    image_check = driver.execute_script("return (arguments[0].width>0 && arguments[0].height>0);", image)
    assert image_check is True, "The image is not displayed"
```

I can't pass `images_list` to `@pytest.mark.parametrize` because it will be unresolved. How is it possible to get  `@pytest.mark.parametrize` fixture working?